# Groupby multiple rows and get values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, jupyter-notebook

I would like to know that how would I get a data like, Date in first column and all stations ID in second column and all respective values of Average Wind speed, Sunshine duration and all and below that, Next date in next row and all stations in column beside this. I have data as below,

```
   Stations_ID  Date    Average windspeed (Beaufort)    sunshine duration   average cloud cover
0   102 2016-01-01  6.8 5.733   NaN
1   164 2016-01-01  1.6 0.000   8.0
2   232 2016-01-01  2.0 0.000   7.8
3   282 2016-01-01  1.2 0.000   7.8
4   183 2016-01-01  2.9 0.000   7.8
... ... ... ... ... ...
164035  4271    2021-12-31  6.7 0.000   7.6
164036  4625    2021-12-31  7.1 0.000   7.3
164037  4177    2021-12-31  2.6 4.167   3.9
164038  4887    2021-12-31  4.7 5.333   3.8
164039  4336    2021-12-31  3.4 0.000   7.4
```

I have used below line of code,

```
df_data_3111 = pd.DataFrame(df_data_311.groupby(['Date','Stations_ID'])['Minimum Temperature'])
```

But this does not work.

Comment: Can you list the names of the columns you're trying to extract? Or a sample of the expected output.

Comment: Please post a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).